# How can I pass data from App.js to components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have App.js and a "uploadlist" functional component. I have defined a 'custid' in app.js and want to pass it to uploadlist component. Here is my try:

app.js:

```
export default class App extends Component {

  state = {

    userrole : '',
    userid   : ''

  };

componentDidMount() {

  if(localStorage.login)
  {
    const currentuser     = JSON.parse(atob(localStorage.login.split(".")[1])); 
    this.setState( {userrole: currentuser.role });
    this.setState( {userid: currentuser.id });
    
  }

}

render() {

if(this.state.userrole === "Customer"){
  const custid=this.state.userid;
  console.log(custid); //This properly returns the custid in console.
return (
//some code
<Route path="/Uploadlist" render={props => <UploadList custid={props.match.params.custid} />}/>
```

uploadlist.js:

```
export default function Uploadlist({custid}) {
    console.log(custid);
```

This doesn't seems to be worked and returns undefined in the console.
How is this to be solved?
How to check if the custid is properly passed from app.js?

Comment: why are you accessing `custId` from `match`, just directly pass`this.state.userid` to `custid` property of `UploadList` component

Comment: How can I do that? @SurajSharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

```
<Route path="/Uploadlist" render={props => <UploadList custid={this.state.userid} />}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

props.match.params.custid

This does not seem right to pass.
Inside your App render component
I would change custId={custId} because you create and assign that variable just above and you need to pass it to the component uploadlist.